# JQuery and Dropdowns in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have 2 dropdowns (main_cat and sub_cat) in wordpress... the second one is disabled and should be enabled when the first one is changed.
When the first dropdown is changed, it enters (to prove this, I added this line alert('The option with value main_cat ' + $mainCat); and the alert shows correctly).
However, the problem comes with this line: jQuery("#sub_cat").prop("disabled", true); because it does nothing.

I checked the code in jsFiddle (jQuery 1.8.3) and it works perfectly, but when placing it in Classipress, it doesn't work. 
I also tried with jQuery("#sub_cat").attr("disabled","disabled");

All the following code is in a child theme.

Any ideas why it is not working or how can I make it work?

HTML

```
 <select name="main_cat" id="main_cat">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Type</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>   
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" disabled="disabled">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Brand</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>   
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery("#main_cat").change(function () {
        var $mainCat = $('#main_cat').val();

        //this is to check that it is entering when main_cat is changed
        alert('The option with value main_cat ' + $mainCat);
        $("#sub_cat").empty();
        jQuery("#sub_cat").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closure has no context of "jQuery", use the $ inside that funciton.

**EDIT**: You will need to remove the "disabled" attribute, as before it was adding it.

```
jQuery("#main_cat").on("change", function(){
   var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();
   alert('The option with value main_cat ' + $mainCat); //this is to check that it is entering when main_cat is changed
   $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried it but still doesn't work... :(

Comment: Can you also try it with "$("#sub_cat").attr("disabled","disabled");"?

I have not used .prop in a long time. I will edit my answer if that works!

Comment: Oh I am sorry, you need to say .prop("disabled", false); or removeAttr("disabled") instead of what were doing here. As we are adding that attribute.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your answers.  Tried all, still doesn't work.  I don't know if the theme I have installed is causing the problem? But then it wouldn't even work the alert that I tried... Is there another way to change the disabled attribute?

Comment: Oh, by the way: $("#sub_cat").empty(); removes all your option elements. Not sure you want it to do that. 

Try that and see if that works. Otherwise, you will need to add some debugger statements and find out why your jquery can't modify the DOM for that element.

Comment: Just removed the $("#sub_cat").empty();  line, and still doesn't work.. I'll try to look what's preventing the modification.  Thanks a lot